# Delphi Rio application doesn't start on Windows 2003 Server (Missing d2d1.dll)

Tags: windows, windows-server, delphi-10.3-rio

Since the Delphi Rio 10.3.3 update (before: Delphi Seattle) my application has not been started on a Windows 2003 server.

Error message like: The application could not be started because d2d1.dll was not found. Reinstalling the application can fix the problem.

I have copied the file d2d1.dll from my PC to the Windows 2003 Server. The following error message appears: The application or DLL d2d1.dll is not a valid Windows file. Check this with the installation chain.

Then I tried to register the DLL via CMD as follows: regscr32 / i d2d1.dll
Error message: d2d1.dll is not an executable file and is not a registration tool that is registered for this file type.

Any ideas? (I know that Windows 2003 Server is very old and nasty but I need any solution)

EDIT: A simple Hello World Application works.

Comment: Maybe you copied a 64bit DLL to a 32bit version of Windows?

Comment: @CherryDT Unfortunately not.. It's a 32bit DLL and 32bit Windows version

Comment: d2d1.dll is a Windows system DLL, which means you can't just copy/paste it into the Windows OS folder. You're going to need to get the right version through Windows Update on your Windows 2003 server. Open an administrator command prompt and run `sfc /SCANNOW` to let Windows check and repair system files. For more info, in that same administrator command prompt type `sfc /?` to view the documentation.

Comment: Direct2D minimum requirements is Server 2008.